# How to format tweets using python through twitter api?

Tags: python, regex, string, twitter, split

I collected some tweets through twitter api. Then I counted the words using `split(' ')` in python. However, some words appear like this:

```
correct! 
correct.
,correct
blah"
...
```

So how can I format the tweets without punctuation? Or maybe I should try another way to `split` tweets? Thanks.

Comment: Any simple solution using `string.punctuation` will undoubtedly mess with emoticons and other special character sequences. If you care about that, you should consider using a tokenizer build for tweets.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do the split on multiple characters using `re.split`...

```
from string import punctuation
import re

puncrx = re.compile(r'[{}\s]'.format(re.escape(punctuation)))
print filter(None, puncrx.split(your_tweet))
```

Or, just find words that contain certain contiguous characters:

```
print re.findall(re.findall('[\w#@]+', s), your_tweet)
```

eg:

```
print re.findall(r'[\w@#]+', 'talking about #python with @someone is so much fun! Is there a     140 char limit? So not cool!')
# ['talking', 'about', '#python', 'with', '@someone', 'is', 'so', 'much', 'fun', 'Is', 'there', 'a', '140', 'char', 'limit', 'So', 'not', 'cool']
```

I did originally have a smiley in the example, but of course these end up getting filtered out with this method, so that's something to be wary of.

Answer (score 1):

Try removing the punctuation from the string before doing the split.

```
import string
s = "Some nice sentence.  This has punctuation!"  
out = s.translate(string.maketrans("",""), string.punctuation)
```

Then do the `split` on `out`.

Answer (score 1):

I would advice to clean text from special symbols before splitting it using this code:

```
tweet_object["text"] = re.sub(u'[!?@#$.,#:\u2026]', '', tweet_object["text"])
```

You would need to import re before using function sub

```
import re
```